# How do I acces data from one objects with 2 other?

Tags: java

So I have class A that creates an object of class B to access it's methods and set variables. However when I create new object of classB in another class all data get's reinitialized. Is there a way where I could have 2 objects accessing data from 1 ?

Comment: Sure. Create the object once, and pass it as argument to the constructor or methods of your classes.

Comment: Use the same instance?  Make the data `static` instead of instance-based?  Use a singleton?  Initialize the objects by materializing a common data source?  There are a variety of things you can do depending on what you need to accomplish.  It's not really clear what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor

```
public class ClassA{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public ClassA(String name, int age) {
     // set attributes
   }

   public ClassA(ClassA clz) {
     // set attributes with value from clz
   }
}
```

Then in your main method

```
ClassA a = new ClassA("Hello", 10);
```

Create another class

```
ClassA b = new ClassA(a); // this is passing values
```

> Is there a way where I could have 2 objects accessing data from 1 ?

If you mean two new objects use the same value, you need [static attributes](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/).

```
public class ClassA{
    public static int count = 1;
}

ClassA c = new ClassA();
ClassA d = new ClassA();
```

Then `count` in `c` and `d` are the same, actually they are using the same `count`. We usually don't need to create a new object to use the value, we use `ClassA.count` directly.

Comment: @asdfs99 glad to hear that, please mark this as answer since it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some form of getters and setters, but unless you are more specific about what you are trying to do or what is wrong it is hard to help.

Comment: So I have 3 classes, Gui, Player and Hangman, Gui class creates player object and sets all variables, then later in the code Hangman creates Player object re setting all the values, can you see this now ?

Comment: In each class for the values that need to change you could add a getter and seter. This works if you have the values in each class set to private.                                                                         
public int getX() {
 return x;
}                                                                                                     public void setX(int x) {
 this.x = x;
}

Comment: @asdfs99: *"then later in the code Hangman creates Player object"* - So now you have two `Player` objects. Consider an analogy... A car is built on an assembly line. You put something in the trunk of that car. Moments later, another car is built on the assembly line. It is identical to the first car in every way. When you open the trunk of the second car, do you expect to see the item you put in the trunk of the first car?

Comment: @David not reall, my player class has all the variables associated with player and I need some options to be set in the GUI object and then take those saved option into Hangman class to do some work, I know that the problem is when creating 2 objects, my question is, is there a way around it ?

Comment: @asdfs99: There are a variety of "ways around it".  For example, if different code should be using the same instance of `Player` then you could pass that instance to the code that needs it when you invoke that code.